# Matching some lines and deleting them with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

**Problem**:

Many files name.CFG with some bad lines in them (roughly 2700 files).  I need to remove the bad lines if they exist.

The bad lines contain the name of the file minus the .CFG

**The Bad Lines**:

```
Title[nameofdevice:cpu]: nameofdevice CPU Usage Mhz
Target[nameofdevice:cpu]:
MaxBytes[nameofdevice:cpu]: 100
Options[nameofdevice:cpu]: gauge
WithPeak[nameofdevice:cpu]: wmy
YLegend[nameofdevice:cpu]: Percent
ShortLegend[nameofdevice:cpu]: %
Legend1[nameofdevice:cpu]: CPU % for 1
Legend2[nameofdevice:cpu]: CPU Max for 2
Legend3[nameofdevice:cpu]: Max CPU Mhz for 1
Legend4[nameofdevice:cpu]: Max CPU Mhz for 2

Title[nameofdevice:mem]: nameofdevice mem
Target[nameofdevice:mem]:
MaxBytes[nameofdevice:mem]: 100
Options[nameofdevice:mem]: gauge
WithPeak[nameofdevice:mem]: wmy
YLegend[nameofdevice:mem]: Percent
ShortLegend[nameofdevice:mem]: %
Legend1[nameofdevice:mem]: % Used
Legend2[nameofdevice:mem]: Max Used
Legend3[nameofdevice:mem]: Max
```

`nameofdevice` is the name of the file minus the .CFG

I was looking for a linux way to do this, but it seems as though Perl would be more flexible. My real issue is matching the text exactly. I guess having the multiple lines and variable are what is perplexing to me, but a small string you could do a find and replace kind of thing. Or use `SED`.

I need to remove the bad lines from all of the files.

Comment: If you have a problem with your Perl program then you should show it and describe what is going wrong. Your problem is unclear. Are you saying that `nameofdevice` should be `nameofdevice.CFG`? In which case, why can't the lines just be corrected instead of deleting them? I assume you want the entire block deleted up to the next blank line? It would help if you showed some valid data as well as the erroneous entries.

Comment: you mean this `sed '/\bnameofdevice\b/d' file`

Comment: I need to delete those lines from every files.  They are exactly the same besides the device name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick (although I believe there's a more efficient way to do this):

```
find -iname '*.cfg' -execdir perl -i -ne '$f = $ARGV =~ s#\./|\.cfg##gr; print if !m/\b\Q$f\E\b/;' {} \+
```

If you're on windows, you need to provide a backup file name for the *inplace* (`-i`) feature:

```
find -iname '*.cfg' -execdir perl -ibak -ne '$f = $ARGV =~ s#\./|\.cfg##gr; print if !m/\b\Q$f\E\b/;' {} \+ && find -iname '*.cfgbak' -delete
```

`find -iname '*.cfg'` finds every `.cfg` file in the current directory and all subdirectories.

The Perl script is:

```
# there's an implied while(<>) because of the -n option
# which executes this script for each line

# $ARGV is the current file path, strip ./ and .cfg
$f = $ARGV =~ s#\./|\.cfg##gr;

# print the current line if it doesn't contain the current file name
# as a whole word
print if !m/\b\Q$f\E\b/;
```

Comment: I suppose I don't understand how this removes the entire block of text above?

Comment: I commented the Perl script - what's the part you don't understand?

Comment: Where is it seeing the above block or is the regex removing that?

I need to get rid of the entire block of text above but in every file the device name is there so it is changing.

Comment: I just suck as asking questions.

Comment: It removes all lines that contain the file name without the `.cfg`. Isn't that what you asked, or did I miss something? You didn't say anything about a *block* in your question.

Comment: "The bad lines" I Need to remove from every CFG.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the one-liner does :) (or I didn't understand the question). Did you try it?

Comment: Okay will this just execute in the directory I run it in. This is important.

Comment: I'm just nervous because the above lines exist in the CFGs, but are filled out with target lines and such

Comment: This will execute in the current directory **and** all subdirectories (add `-maxdepth 1` after `find` if you need only the current directory). And **always do a backup of your files before doing a mass update operation like this one**.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep -P` (PCRE):

```
grep -P 'nameofdevice(?!\.CFG)' file
```

To skip these lines:

```
grep -v -P 'nameofdevice(?!\.CFG)' file > tmpFile
mv tmpFIle file
```

Comment: But I need to remove the bad lines from every CFG not remove the name

Comment: That is the entire block above needs to be removed if it exists in the file

Comment: Did you check my `grep -v` command which prints all but matching lines on output

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i.bak -ne '$n=$ARGV=~s/\.cfg$//r; print unless /\b$n\b/' *.cfg
```

or even

```
... print unless /\b\Q$n\E\b/
```

It will create a backup (file.cfg.bak)

Comment: I need to delete this block of text above "The Bad Lines" not remove the name.

Comment: Basically I need to load the file and see if it contains the above bad lines and if it does delete them.

Comment: Although in each file the bad lines contain the name of each file

Comment: That's exactly what the one-liner does :) (or I didn't understand the question).  Suggestion: try it with 2 or 3 files `perl ...... file1.cfg file2.cfg`, calculate the differences  `diff file1.cfg fil1.cfg.bak`